# How to determine if data point was placed in training or testing set?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using `train_test_split` to split image data for a convolutional neural network in Python:

`x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)`

For each image in `X`, how can I figure out whether it was sent to the `x_train` or `x_test` set? Since all the data in the `x_train` or `x_test` datasets are in tensor form and randomized, I'm not sure how to relate a given instance in `x_train`/`x_test` back to its original place in `X`. My confusion matrix is printing inconsistent information, so I'm trying to figure out if the way the data is split being training and testing is the reason.

Edit 1: Folder Structure
All the images are in one array (`X = np.array(X_images)`) which I derived from collecting image from folders such that:

Data

- Class_1
- Class_2
  ...
- Class_n

I then used: `Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)` to get the Y values

Comment: Are you making X and Y from folders? Like giving the path of folders and making X and Y? Can you show the folder structure?

Comment: @PrakashDahal Edited question to show above

Comment: is class_1, class_2, .... class_n your folder names from where you have derived X? is your label name class_1, class_2 ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to  re-run the experiment, try generating indicates instead of raw arrays. Then use indicates to extract train and dev sets.

```
# this is slightly modified example from the sklearn documentation:

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
X = np.array([["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"]])
y = np.array(["a1", "c1", "e1", "g1"])
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("indicates", "TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) takes as arguments an arbitrary number of arrays/vectors, so you could just pass an additional list/array containing some identifier to that call, e.g. `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, id_train, id_test = train_test_split(X, y, ids)`, where `ids` is some list/array containing the identifiers corresponding to each element in `X`/`y`. Then, the data point at index `i` in `X_train`/`y_train` will correspond to the identifier at `id_train[i]`, and so on for the "test" data. If you don't have a row-identifier column handy, you could just use the index of `X`, e.g. `ids = list(range(X.shape[0]))`.

Answer (score 0):

The following solved my problem. I created a numpy array from the original image data:

`indices = np.arange(X.shape[0])`

Fed this into the `train_test_split` function call and added two more that created an index corresponding to the image's respective `X` index:

`x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, x_train_ind, x_test_ind = train_test_split(X, Y, indices, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)`

After getting the index of an image in the `x_train` dataset, we can plug that into `x_train_ind` to get the index in the original `X` dataset